# Longitudinal Analysis: GCM: Help understanding SPSS output

Tags: mixed-model, spss, panel-data

I am working on a longitudinal analysis (SPSS Mixed). Based on graphing the data and the descriptive statistics, I am expecting a cubic growth curve. I am a bit confused about my SPSS output. The books I've been reading say that you need to do it in parametric order - linear, quadratic, and then cubic. However, when I do that, the linear growth curve is not significant. Thank you for your help.

Type III Tests of Fixed Effects (Linear Growth Curve)
Source  Numeratordf Denominatordf   F        Sig.
Intercept   1        362.313      257.632   .000
time        1        306.567      .923      .337
a. Dependent Variable: totalsupport.

Type III Tests of Fixed Effects (Quadratic Growth Curve)
Source  Numeratordf Denominatordf   F        Sig.
Intercept   1         383.209     296.248   .000
time        1         2777.642    45.351    .000
time_square 1         4129.159    69.246    .000
a. Dependent Variable: totalsupport.

Type III Tests of Fixed Effects (Cubic Growth Curve)
Source  Numeratordf Denominatordf   F        Sig.
Intercept   1        401.746     268.254    .000
time        1        4304.292     .151      .697
time_square 1        4038.650     6.464     .011
time_cube   1        4029.445     16.685    .000
a. Dependent Variable: totalsupport.

Answer (score 0):

General advice here would be to include the linear and quadratic effects when you include a cubic effect, even if their tests are not significant. Note that you can look at Type I tests instead of Type III tests to see tests for linear on top of just an intercept, then quadratic on top of linear and intercept, then cubic on top of intercept, linear, and quadratic.